# index + 1 array null pointer

Tags: java, arrays

Problem: Given a sorted array, remove the duplicates in place such that each element appear only once and return the new length.

Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this in place with constant memory.

Example
Given input array A = [1,1,2],

Your function should return length = 2, and A is now [1,2].

My solution:

```
public int removeDuplicates(int[] nums) {

    if(nums.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int size = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if((i + 1) <= nums.length && (nums[i] != nums[i + 1])) {
            nums[size] = nums[i];
            size++;
        }
    }

}
```

The problem that I am running into is a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the second if statement:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 at Solution.removeDuplicates(Solution.java:15) at Main.main(Main.java:10)

I do not understand why because I am checking if i+1 <= the length of the array, which should prevent the overflow error.

Comment: Just want to point out that `(i + 1) <= nums.length` is just a clumsy way of writing `i < nums.length`, which is the normal way of writing it. You don't need to check this, because you're already checking it in the for loop. Just remove it completely.

Comment: It seems you increment i twice?

Comment: null pointer exceptions have nothing to do with checking array indexes.  Are you sure this is a null pointer exception?  Please post the error message and/or stack trace you're getting.

Comment: @Gendarme it's worse since after checking he uses `nums[i + 1]` that will break when `i + 1` equals `nums.length`.

Comment: `nums[i + 1]` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, not a NPE, though.

Comment: you want to use `<` not `<=` for comparisons against length. Remember, an array with length==1 can only index `array[0]`. If you're going to index with `i+1`, then you must check if `i+1 < nums.length`

Comment: @Gendarme true still an issue though. Something else is throwing a NPE before it can fail.

Comment: Code in the post can't reasonably throw NPE where you claim it to. Please provide [MCVE] or consider to delete the question before it gets appropriately downvoted.

Comment: @twain249 I suspect he mistakenly wrote NPE instead of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, though. But there is no way to know until we get a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the "i + 1 <= nums.length" to "i + 1 < nums.length". When your variable (i) is at the end of loop (i + 1) will be out of array. For example A = [1,1,2] and the length is 3. In the for loop i will be 2 and i+1 will be 3 so nums[3] wil be out of bound.

```
     for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if((i + 1) < nums.length && (nums[i] != nums[i + 1])) {
            nums[size] = nums[i];
            size++;
        }
        else if(i + 1 == nums.length) 
            num[size] = nums[i];
     }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Also, thanks for the clear explanation.